# How To Secure SQL Server Credentials In Java Web Service Applicaiton

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, rest

I'm creating a RESTful Web Service with Spring that will run on the same server that my Microsoft SQL Server runs on (which runs Ubuntu).

I want my web service to access the database and send data back to the client. What I want to know is, what is the proper method for logging into my SQL server from my web service?

I could hardcode the credentials (or keep them in a file) but that seems less than secure. What other options does SQL Server/JDBC driver offer? Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use datasource variable references in your server, example wildfly
this video will be very helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlUuzvQuCTs